# How do I create a landscape layout like Google Play's movies section?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

When you you click on a movie in Google Play and go to landscape mode, the image is in the background and the details of a movie is on a layout above the background. These 2 surfaces scroll together. How can I do that?

Movie Section Google Play Movie Example

[image: Movie Section Google Play Movie Example]

I have collapsing toolbar (the background image is here) and I tried anchoring the entire nested scrollview to the app bar. But that doesn't work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:expandedTitleMargin="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_movie_detail_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/scrim"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/scrollview_movie_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ImageView` should have the usual flag (`parallax`) : `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` and it should be in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

About the content you see, just add:

```
app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp" // 100dp for example
```

To your `NestedScrollView` (or anything like `RecyclerView` which has: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`).

There is a good sample in here which you can use: https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample